# Import Jetpack Compose Card component not importing

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I just created a new project with the below dependencies for material 3.

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

I am not being able to import the Card component.

```
 Card(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        elevation = 4.dp,
        backgroundColor = Color.White
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello, World!")
            Text(text = "This is a card")
        }
    }
```

What am I missing for the import to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember I had such problem before, it was that because version `1.0.0-alpha01` of `androidx.compose.material3:material3` didn't introduce `Card` composable yet, it was an early alpha version.
That is resolved in higher versions, try updating it to the latest stable version `1.0.1`, you should be able to import the `Card` composable then. So you should have your implementation like this:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1"
```